# $L^2$ and $C^0$ norms combined

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, banach-spaces

We know that $L^2$ and $C^0$ are complete metric spaces.

Now consider for fixed $T$ the space of real-valued processes $X:\Omega\times [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ (with corresponding $\sigma$-algebra) such that

$$\Vert X \Vert = \mathbb E [\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T} |X_s| ^2] ^{1/2}< \infty$$

Is this a closed complete metric space?

**My attempt:** It must be. This space is a subspace of $L^2$ and therefore every Cauchy sequence in the above sense has $L^2$ limit. However, I don't see if this space is closed (i.e. $L^2$ limit also has finite norm in the above sense).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $X_k$? Is your $t$ fixed all must this sup hold for all $t$? Are your functions mapping from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ I assume? What limit are you talking about? Are we actually talking about a space of stochastic processes?

Comment: Edited, hopefully it's clearer now. Since I am trying to prove completeness, the limit I am talking about is that of a Cauchy sequence in the above norm.

Comment: If your space consists of functions $X:\mathbb  R\to \mathbb R$ then $\mathbb E[\sup_{s\leq t}|X_s|^2]=\sup_{s\leq t}|X_s|^2\int_\mathbb{R}dx=\infty$ for all functions that aren't $0$ on $[0,t]$.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't considering stochastic processes on some underlying measure space?

Comment: Sorry, got confused, you are right!

Comment: I don't think $\|\cdot\|$ even defines a norm here. Are you forgetting a square root?

Comment: Isn't every metric space closed (in itself) by definition? You only need to check you have a metric and then show completeness afterwards.. .

Comment: Just to be clear: You assume that $X$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega\times [0,T]$?

Comment: It seems that you are working with $L^2(\Omega; L^\infty([0,T]))$ a mixed or vector-valued version of $L^2$. Those are complete.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience let us denote this space $S$. I believe we can adapt the standard argument showing completion of the $L^p$ spaces. Let $(X^{(n)})\subset S$ be such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|X^{(n)}\|<\infty$. To show completeness of $S$ it suffices to show that $(\sum_{n=1}^NX^{(n)})_N$ converges to some $X\in S$ in norm. We propose that this $X$ is actually $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X^{(n)}$.

We note that $\sup_{s\leq T}|X_s|^2=\left(\sup_{s\leq T}|X_s|\right)^2$. Thus, for any $N\in \mathbb N$, by the Minkowski inequality,
$$\mathbb E\left[\sup_{s\leq T}|\sum_{n=1}^NX^{(n)}_s|^2\right]^{1/2}\leq\mathbb E\left[(\sum_{n=1}^N\sup_{s\leq T}|X^{(n)}_s|)^2\right]^{1/2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E[\sup_{s\leq T}|X^{(n)}_s|^2]^{1/2}=\sum_{n=1}^N\|X^{(n)}\|.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\mathbb E\left[\sup_{s\leq T}|\sum_{n=1}^NX^{(n)}_s|^2\right]^{1/2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|X^{(n)}\|<\infty.$$
Now $\omega\mapsto (\sup_{s\leq T}\sum_{n=1}^N|X^{(n)}_s(\omega)|)^2$ converges to $\omega\mapsto (\sup_{s\leq T}\sum_{n=1}^\infty |X^{(n)}_s(\omega)|)^2$ pointwise monotonically, so the monotone convergence theorem thus gives us that
$$\mathbb E\left[(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sup_{s\leq T}|X^{(n)}_s|)^2\right]^{1/2}<\infty,$$
from which we deduce that
$$\|X\|<\infty,$$
so $X\in S$, and $X$ is finite on a set of full measure. It also means for each $N\in\mathbb N$ that $\omega\mapsto \sup_{s\leq T}\sum_{n=1}^N|X_s^{(n)}(\omega)| $ is bounded by an $L^2$ function $\omega\mapsto \sup_{s\leq T}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|X_s^{(n)}(\omega)| $.

This implies that $\sup_{s\leq T}|X_s-\sum_{n=1}^NX^{(n)}_s|$ is also bounded by an $L^2$ function (via triangle inequality), so by the dominated convergence theorem 
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\mathbb E\left[\sup_{s\leq T}|X_s-\sum_{n=1}^NX^{(n)}_s|^2\right]^{1/2}=0.$$
Thus the partial sums of $(X^{(n)})$ indeed converge to $X$ in $S$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: I don't quite see where the dominated convergence is applied here. In particular which sequence is point wise converging (or in measure) and by what is it dominated?

Comment: @Shashi thanks for pointing that out. I rushed through my argument and muddled up my use of the MCT and DCT. Please have a look at my edit when you have time.

Comment: Yes now it is clear! Thanks for clarifying things.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error!